# Wireframe thickness like sketchup and color without rendering

Tags: wireframe

Is there a way to change wireframe color and thicknes on 3d objects without rendering them?
The default wireframe appear is only one pixel, so I would like to increase it and also change color. If possible on only some objects.

Bellow is the desired effect in "object mode" without any object selected, I can use python if necessary.
[image]

Currently I have wire checked to do this but I can't choose color by object or wire thickness:
[image: blender]

Just for information, I am no expert in 3D modeling. I jut use blender as 3d view with python scripts to import 3d objs dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

In *File*> *User Preferences*> *Themes*> *3D View* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) you can change the 'Active Object' colour and 'Outline Width' property:

[image]

If you want to change the colour of multiple selected objects' outlines, you will also need to change the 'Object Selected' colour. The 'Active Object' property will only change the colour of the outline for the last selected object.

[image]

Increasing 'Outline Width' give this effect:

[image]

As far as I can see, you can't change the thickness of the 'Edit mode' wire, only the 'Object mode' wire.

Comment: thank you for the sugestion. however I would like to do this without select any object, is that possible? Also change the color of the ouline by object.

Comment: @Hedzx There is no option in the user preferences to change the outline width for an object that isn't selected. To change the colour per-object you would currently need to use a gooseberry build (I think) from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/), but the thicker outline would still only effect selected objects.